# Getting None of [] are in the [columns] error when using isin function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I would like to get a subset of indices in a pandas data frame using a certain column. However, when I use list of values as my subset, I receive an error which seems like a very common error faced by other users. I've tried different solutions proposed in the previos posts, but none of them helped me.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5,6,3,4,5], 'B': [1,2,3,5,1]})
#I create a new column combining the first two columns
df["C"] = df['A'].astype(str) +"-"+ df["B"].astype(str)

#Then, I randomly select two values from the unique values coming from column C
uniqueVal = pd.unique(df["C"])
my_subset = uniqueVal[np.random.choice(len(uniqueVal), size=2, replace=False)]

#Let's print my_subset
print(my_subset)
array(['3-3', '4-5'], dtype=object)

#Now, I would like to get all the rows containing my_subset values in column C
df[df['C']].isin(my_subset)
```

Here, I get the error as:

```
"None of [Index(['5-1', '6-2', '3-3', '4-5', '5-1'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grouping for when you check if df's C col is in your list is done improperly

It should be of the format df[condition]

```py
#change the last line
print(df[df['C'].isin(my_subset)])
```

output

```
   A  B    C
2  3  3  3-3
3  4  5  4-5
```